# Help Diagnosing Freezing Linux Host

Tags: linux, stability

I have a home built system that I've had random complete system freezes happen that I can only physically power down and start up the system. The network access is gone (I do a fair bit of remote SSH), keyboard/mouse operations fail. But I did still have visual on the desktop on the last freeze within PopOS.

I'm guessing that I have a system incompatibility or other driver challenge that I'm not sure how to proceed. I have tried multiple OS including Ubuntu 23, Fedora 38, PopOS 22.04. PopOS seems to work the longest, at 3 days so far.

### Hardware

| Hardware Item | Component |
| --- | --- |
| Motherboard | ASUS B760M-CT-CSM |
| Processor | Intel Core i5-12600K |
| RAM | 128 GB TEAMGROUP Elite DDR5 (4800MHz PC5-38400 CL40 Unbuffered Non-ECC 1.1V UDIMM 288) |
| Storage | Samsung 980 Pro SSD NVMe |
| GPU | NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER |

Any advice where to head on troubleshooting? Any tests that I can run?

Comment: I'd start by double checking all the connectors are firmly seated. I'd also run a memory soak test (memtest86+). I'd check online for compatibility issues with your Nvidia and ensure I had the latest driver. Maybe Nouveau might work in the interim

Comment: In addition to the ram check suggested by roaima, it would also be worthwhile to check the kernel messages.  Use `dmesg -w` to watch the kernel log.  If you see regular updates it could be signs of a hardware problem--and what hardware.  Might also show you the last thing to happen before lockup.  Run into this problem myself and not easy to diagnose.

Comment: The memory soak test was a perfect thing for that. Some good results and followed up with a full test of each memory stick. I'm encouraged and things are in a decent state at this point.